# Node.js FS module start prob

Tags: node.js

Ok so node.js has been driving me crazy. I have been trying to run the exact same code from the book. But it throwing me an error. The code is simple and watches a file for changes

```
   const fs= require('fs');

fs.watch('target.txt', function() {
console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
 });
 console.log("Now watching target.txt for changes");
```

the js file for the code and text.txt is in the same dir. And I get this error

```
$ node --harmony watcher.js

 fs.js:1051
throw errnoException(process._errno, 'watch');
      ^
Error: watch ENOENT
at errnoException (fs.js:1019:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1051:11)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1076:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\Sinan\try\watcher.js:5:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Thanks beforehand. 
I would also appropriate an uptodate source for learning node, I have tried 2 books and I can not even run example codes

Comment: `ENOENT` means it cannot find the file. just curious, can you `fs.stat('target.txt',console.log)`? let's see if its a problem with `fs.watch` or with your implementation.

Comment: it worked for a second and then printed error

 
    Now watching target.txt for changes
    { [Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\cygwin64\home\Sinan\try\target.txt']
      errno: 34,
      code: 'ENOENT',
      path: 'C:\\cygwin64\\home\\Sinan\\try\\target.txt' }

Comment: @sinanspd It's late but i had a similar problem today. Check if the file that you created and the file you are watching have same name. In my case it was more of a typo.

Comment: Nah sorry I replied late also. It turns out there was a problem with my C++ runtime codes in windows itself and it was preventing whatever I do in node.js from running properly. A format took care of it thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 0):

I removed .txt extension and it worked.

```
fs.watch('target', function () {
    console.log("File target.txt just changed");
});
```